# Concatenante and include leading zeroes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

So currently I am pulling numbers from a spreadsheet that automatically formats their numbers into a certain amount of digits using special number formatting, so that it outputs with leading zeroes.

Example:

(zipcode formatting) 6 digits - 
12345 becomes 012345

(Chinese (PRC) formatting) 6 digits - 
12 becomes 000012

(Chinese (Taiwan) formatting) 3 digits - 
0 becomes 000

My concatenate would put them together with periods between them; however, it does the base numbers instead of the formatting it should be doing.

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,".",B1,".",C1)
```

012345 000012 000 becomes 12345.12.0 instead of 012345.000012.000
Is there a function or something that will work to make it pull the converted special number instead of the one typed? It should ALWAYS be 6 digits.6 digits.3 digits.

Comment: I would look into `=TEXT()`. This will allow you to format the numbers as text with whatever format you would like.

Comment: Genius! haha, I forgot that even existed. =CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"00000"),".",TEXT(B1,"000000"),".",TEXT(C1,"000")) works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
= TEXT(12345,"######000000") & "." & TEXT(12,"######000000") & "." & TEXT(0,"###000")
```

Comment: Would you use that over =CONCATENATE(TEXT(A1,"00000"),".",TEXT(B1,"000000"),".",TEXT(C1,"000")) for quicker processing?

Comment: @Xiodrade Not sure what is the difference between `CONCATENATE` vs. just `&`. I usually just use `&` because it is shorter haha. But I don't know which one is objectively better in terms of speed, efficiency, etc.

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot.

Comment: @Xiodrade After a quick google search, looks like there's not much difference between the two. I guess `CONCATENATE` exists just to give you the option of having a function with arguments, but it seems like it is just personal preference.